# Skype video turns off

Tags: macos, audio, video, skype, webcam

I've been having a problem with Skype on a Mac System running 10.8.  Whenever I start a video call with a contact, *my* video feed turns itself off after various amounts of time.  The option to turn the video stream back on is completely disabled (greyed out).  The call does continue however, I still receive the other caller's video feed, and audio is transmitted perfectly.

I have replaced my router, as it was old and was dropping packets, but the problem persists.
I have followed Skype's [instructions](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12073/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-and-then-reinstall-skype-for-mac-os-x), and have completely uninstalled and reinstalled skype.  I have checked the firmware for the webcam and found it to be up to date.  I have installed all system updates.

Besides completely reinstalling the OS, is there any other way to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a service provider level problem.  How did you determine your router was dropping packets exactly?

Comment: As in my ISP?  I pinged my router ip / default gateway and found packet loss.  I'm sure theres probably a better way to do that.  The router was 13 years old anyway so I assumed that was the problem.

Comment: Any more assistance here?  Is my ISP possibly at fault?  Should I attempt to format and reinstall my computer?

Comment: A reinstall of an operating system won't resolve your problem

Comment: @Ramhound how so?  The problem does seem limited to skype.  I am going to try a different webcam program and see If I get the same problem.

Comment: If you feel it will solve the problem, your welcome to do it, I am just trying to save you from the trouble of doing so not acomplish nothing.

Comment: @Ramhound so do you have anything to add that may narrow down the cause of this problem? thank you

Comment: Your internet provider is using DPI and Skype traffic is being given a lower priority then the rest of your traffic.  You don't indicate what sort of time frame, I assume its quick, otherwise it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Gotcha, you could have said that in the first place ;) It occurs after varying abouts of time, anywhere from 3 minutes to 8 minutes.  Would you suspect this same problem would occur with other VOIP services?

Comment: Also, wouldn't DPI be visible in other programs, not just Skype? Slow down of videos for example? Also using a VPN should possibly fix the problem?

Comment: DPI can be targeted towards specific packets.  A VPN might help might do nothing